# Wrong activity status when public sign up for a volunteer opportunity

Tags: civivolunteer, activity

After registering for a given volunteer opportunity with the public signup form, an activity record is created with an activity status = completed. In a test installation of mine, the status is correctly = scheduled.
This problem has some very badly consequences for the functionality of the CiviVolunteer extension.

Does anybody has any ideas how to fix that problem?
I would be extremely appreciated for any helpful comments!

Answer (score 2):

For all of you who also have this problem:

I managed to solve the problem with the CiviRules extension!

See this screenshot for configuring

[image]